# How to pass routeValues to Html.ActionLink in asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

We can pass single int parameter as below.

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.RemoteAgent.Name, "Details", "RemoteAgent", new { id = item.RemoteAgent.Id })
```

But what if we want to pass complex object?
what can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the model in client side,and then deserialize it in action.Here is a demo.
Model:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@{ TestModel m=new TestModel { FirstName="f1",MiddleName="m1",LastName="l1"};}
@Html.ActionLink("Index1", "Index1", "A", new { model = Json.Serialize(m)})
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult Index1(string model)
        {
            TestModel testModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestModel>(model);

            return Ok();
        }
```

result:

[image]